# How do I Re-Light My 1995 Magic Chef free stand stove Model# 3110PRW & the pilot Light for the Oven also needs Lit?

Tags: stove, pilot-light, fire-safety

It’s my vacation home ,It was working until I removed burner plates, to clean stove top. Next day it wouldnt turn on, even with a match,  The pilot light for the oven , off also ? Do they work off one pilot? Thank you, for any help you can give( I’m a senior, alone & staying in- Social distancing ..coronavirus )

Comment: This is my first time on this (seems to be ..magnificent site).. how can I tell, if their are others on site, at this hour? I’ve just realized  it’s 1am..

Comment: In many ovens, the main gas valve is controlled by a thermocouple that senses the pilot light.  That way if the pilot isn't lit, then there's no way to open the main gas valve (which is a good thing.)  When I Google this model number, the parts lists mention an igniter, which would mean there is no pilot and your problem may lie there instead.

Comment: MIght be a coincidence if your tank ran low just at that time, if you have a tank rather than a natural gas line from the street.   And just to be a bother, did you make sure there's still electrical power (plugged in,  oven light comes on, etc)?

Comment: `I’ve just realized it’s 1am` ... it may be true where you are, but it is noon some other places